# how I can Apply Dilation on binary image , matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

how I can Apply Dilation , Erosion, Closing and Opening to a binary image with the following structuring element
[001
011 
111]
 by using matlab ??

Plz if you have any related matlab code upload it here , I am web developer I take this course to complete the graduation requirement just .

Comment: Don't have the image processing toolbox? Have a look at `filter2` and think about thresholding.

Comment: try `imdilate` or `imerode`.

Comment: You can also search for dilation and erosion pseudo-code on web and try to understand the logic and them implement by yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below shows how to use a customized structuring element or neighborhood in MATLAB. Similar code can be used for erode, close and open.

```
a = imread('peppers.png');
a1 = rgb2gray(a);
a2 = imdilate(a1, [0 0 1; 0 1 1; 1 1 1]);
```